# Getting exception on creating react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**Command**

1. npm init react-app my-test-app
2. cd my-test-app
3. npm install

**Error Logs**

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/dev1/.npm/_logs/2022-05-15T10_12_55_434Z-debug.log
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.7.0 presetup: `npm i chalk shelljs`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@3.7.0 presetup script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/dev1/.npm/_logs/2022-05-15T10_12_55_434Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the command sequence you've shown (although `npm install` is not necessary -- the app should be all set up by the first command). What happens if you just do `npm start` in the `my-test-app` directory?

Comment: Its likely that you have to remove your ~/.npmrc